# How to detect which JavaScript function is running on my web page

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I have designed a web page using Gsap. there are too many functions on different events on my web page like onload, onscroll etc. There is an issue on the page, that is getting scrolled unnecessarily.

I am unable to detect which JS function is causing this issue. Is there a way in the Chrome Dev tool that can detect the currently running function so i can fix it.

Comment: Can you add a [example]?